# How can I do find and highlight text in outlook

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am developing outlook web-Addin visual studio share point developing tool.i want to find a specific word in the document and highlight that word.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) We’re happy to help, but not write an entire solution for you.

Comment: i am developing an Addin in "MessageComposeCommandSurface" i want to find a specific word in the document and highlight the text .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vishnu Kay Vee

Currently the feature you requested is not a part of the product. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

[Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team]

Answer (score -6):

1. In the email message or item you're creating, on the **Format Text** tab, in the Editing group, choose **Find**.
2. In the Find what box, type the text that you want to search for.
3. Choose **Reading Highlight** > **Highlight All**.

[image]

**Note:** To turn off highlighting on the screen, choose Reading Highlight > Clear Highlighting.

This link will help you about Find and replace text within an email message or item: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-and-replace-text-within-an-email-message-or-item-ee05a4ac-6c30-4687-8098-84f4390d2d6f

Comment: The question is about creating an add-in, not how the user can  highlight text for reading.